# counting the larger value

Tags: r, counting

Completely new to R and am trying to count how many numbers in a list are larger than the one right before.

This is what I have so far,

```
count <- 0
number <- function(value) {
for (i in 1:length(value)) 
  { if(value[i+1] > value[i])
  {count <- count + 1}
  }
}
x <- c(1,2,1,1,3,5)
number(x)
```

The output should be 3 based on the list.

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A base R alternative would be `diff`

```
sum(diff(x) > 0)
#[1] 3
```

---

Or we can also eliminate first and last values and compare them.

```
sum(x[-1] > x[-length(x)])
#[1] 3
```

where

```
x[-1]
#[1] 2 1 1 3 5
x[-length(x)]
#[1] 1 2 1 1 3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `lag` your vector and count how many times your initial vector is greater than your lagged vector

```
library(dplyr)
sum(x>lag(x), na.rm = TRUE)
```

---

In details, `lag(x)` does:

```
> lag(x)
[1] NA  1  2  1  1  3
```

so `x > lag(x)` does

```
> x>lag(x)
[1]  NA  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

The sum of the above is 3.